# Variables declared outside the class

Tags: python, class

Pressing button A prints *myVariable* variable declared outside MainWindow() class scope definition.

```
print  '\n\t myVariable =', myVariable
```

A class function (method) linked to button B wants to:

1. To print out myVariable
2. to assign to myVariable a new value (11)
3. To print this variable again.

But buttonB_func() fails with a very first line throwing a UnboundLocalError:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myVariable' referenced before assignment
```

Aside from knowing how to fix it it would be interesting to find out why that happens in a first place. 
P.s. Making a variable global by using:

```
global myVariable
myVariable=10
```

doesn't help.

```
myVariable=10

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        buttonA = QtGui.QPushButton("Button A")
        buttonA.clicked.connect(self.buttonA_func)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(buttonA)     


        buttonB = QtGui.QPushButton("Button B")
        buttonB.clicked.connect(self.buttonB_func)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(buttonB) 

        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def buttonA_func(self):
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', myVariable, '\n'

    def buttonB_func(self):
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', myVariable, '\n'
        myVariable=11
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', myVariable, '\n'



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(480, 320)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That's how python looks up variables. It will try to look up the value of the variable from the most local scope to the global. Read this: "http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python". That first paragraph should give you the answer your are looking for. As for the error, just include the line, "global myVariable" at the start of Button_B's function. This will define the scope of the variable to allow you to change the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `global` inside the method body before you attempt to use the variable.

Comment: Why should be 'global' declaration placed inside of method and not outside? It appears that 'global' must be put inside the class's method that uses the variable... in this case it should be placed inside of buttonB_func(self) method. Placing global inside __init__ results the same UnboundLocalError as before.... actually, global needs to be placed inside of every method that uses the variable.

Comment: Because that is what the docs say. It should be used in order for a variable in a block to be treated as a global. It should go in any function or method where you want it treated as a global.

Comment: It appears to get a read-only access to a variable we don't have to declare it as GLOBAL (inside of method). But for a read-and-write access to the same variable we need to go ahead and put a 'global myVariable' statement ( inside of each method).

Comment: It has nothing to do with read/write access. The issue is scope -- the global statement causes identifiers to be treated with global, rather than local scope. Think of it like like getting a reference to an item and modifying what it points to, rather than a new stack allocation that goes away once the function returns.

Comment: to be clear, though, you can freely read a global variable without declaring it as such in the local scope.

Comment: I think the confusion is the exception being raised when assigning. This is caused by Python seeing the assignment and assuming it is a local, but then referenced it in the same statement and assuming it is not yet defined.

Comment: I see. As soon as Python encounters a same name variable mentioned within a scope (method's or function's) it assumes (by reason) it's a local. To override this Python 'defaults' use 'global myVariable' statement. Thanks again!

Comment: The assignment causes it to be treated as local, if it is local, it can not exist until after the assignment, hence the exception being thrown. There are many ways to handle this, but a simple attribute is probably all you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The locality of a variable is determined at compile time. Whenever you assign to a variable (with out usage of `global` or `nonlocal`) this variable becomes local to that scope (stored either fast or dereferred). In button A, you don't assign to it, hence it works. In button B you assign to it, hence it is local and fails. As @Ben pointed out, if you put a `global myVariable` as first line of `buttonB_func`, this should fix your problem. But the question is: Why use global variables?

---

As @AdamCushner has pointed you can make your variable a member of your class. Something along these lines:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    myVariable=10

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def buttonA_func(self):
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', MainWindow.myVariable, '\n'

    def buttonB_func(self):
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', MainWindow.myVariable, '\n'
        MainWindow.myVariable=11
        print  '\n\t\t\t myVariable =', MainWindow.myVariable, '\n'
```

Comment: There are situations when I just can't see an alternative way and not to use the global variables. It is most likely because of lack of knowledge.

Comment: why not make it a member of the class?